# sharepoint 2010 search service round robin error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, load-balancing

We have one sharepoint server (sp1) and the database server (db5).  To get some features of sharepoint to work, we installed sharepoint on the db5 server.

The sharepoint search service topology does not show db5 as a query component, but (apparently) randomly, the round robin system returns the db5 server in the url to the search service.  this causes an error:

> EventID: 8313 SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load
>   Balancer Event: EndpointFailure Process Name: w3wp Process ID: 11352
>   AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/793880394/ROOT-1-130661322414428557
>   AppDomain ID: 2 Service Application Uri:
>   urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:ac46e57625f540e592ef16d8cafbae41#authority=urn:uuid:6a161a722144223e6a4d11faa95b89994&authority=https://sp1:32542/Topology/topology.svc
>   Active Endpoints: 1 Failed Endpoints:1
>
> Affected Endpoint:
>   http://db5:32542/ac46e57625f540e593ef18d8cafbae41/SearchService.svc

the correct address should not have the http://db5:32542...I believe it should be http://sp1:32542.

I have a suspicion that the problem is in the load balancing/round robin.  Somehow there is a setting that allows sharepoint to serve the db5 server as the host.

I want to remove db5 as an available server in the load balancer/round robin system.

Comment: I found a consistent 10 minute timeframe between errors.  This page talks about the 10 minutes [link].(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtaylor/archive/2011/02/23/sharepoint-2010-service-application-load-balancer.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try :

- Run Get-SPServiceInstance
- Located the ID of the Project Application Service.
- Run Stop-SPServiceInstance ServiceID
- Wait and confirm the service was stopped by running `Get-SPServiceInstance` again
- Run `Start-SPServiceInstance ServiceID`

Comment: It turns out that either restarting IIS or doing what you posted here as the answer works.  Also, it appears that running the sharepoint services on the DB server is not appropriate, so I have my work cut out to get this all fixed.  Thanks for checking in on my question.